# why are some of my path not added?

Tags: windows-10, path, sublime-text-3, sublime-text-2, latex

I want to run sublime and latex from USB Drive.
This is the [tutorial](https://codeslake.github.io/windows10/sublime%20text%203/setting-portable-sublime-with-latextools/).

It does not work correctly because the path are not added succesfully.

This is my batch file to add the path.

```
del restorePath.txt
echo %path% >> restorePath.txt
setx path "%path%"
setx path "%~dp0SumatraPDF"
setx path "%~dp0Sublime_Text_Build_3211_x64"
setx path "%~dp0MikTex\MikTex\texmfs\install\miktex\bin\x64"
setx path "%~dp0MikTex\MikTex\texmfs"
setx path "%~dp0ImageMagick-7.0.10-23-portable-Q16-HDRI-x64"
setx sublime "%~dp0Sublime_Text_Build_3211_x64"

PAUSE
```

Sublime can check all the software required.
It is shown that it cannot find the path for Latex and SumatraPDF.
But somehow it can add path for ImageMagick.

Am I missing something in my batch file?

[image: sublime]

Answer (score 0):

ooops...sorry.

This works:

```
del restorePath.txt
echo %path% >> restorePath.txt
setx path "%path%;%~dp0SumatraPDF;%~dp0Sublime_Text_Build_3211_x64;%~dp0MikTex\MikTex\texmfs\install\miktex\bin\x64;%~dp0MikTex\MikTex\texmfs;%~dp0ImageMagick-7.0.10-23-portable-Q16-HDRI-x64"
setx sublime "%~dp0Sublime_Text_Build_3211_x64"

PAUSE
```

I used that batch file before but somehow it did not work.
That is why I changed it and made it line by line.

There are still some parts missing, but the path works.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYtUM.png)